# How to bound types inside function arguments

Tags: typescript, generics

Is it possible to check types of an one argument based on an other argument in functions? There is an example:

```js
interface Data {
  id?: number;
  name?: string;
}

let data : Data = {};

// have no idea how to strict "value" argument
function update(field : keyof Data, value) {
  data[field] = value;
}

update('id', 0);             // [1] ok
update('name', 'foo');       // [2] ok
update('id', 'some string'); // [3] FAIL ("id" must be a number)
update('name', 123);         // [4] FAIL ("name" must be a string)
update('other', 123);        // [5] FAIL ("other" isn't possible argument)
```

I am not sure it is possible to do that way. In the example only call number `[5]` will fail.

Comment: Your `data` isn't really a constant, so `const` is pretty confusing

Comment: @AlexeyPyzhianov that is acceptable for objects. Anyway updated to `let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a generic which can be any key of `Data` and then get the type of K with `Data[K]`.

```
function update<K extends keyof Data>(field: K, value: Data[K]) {
   data[field] = value;
}
```

with this 1 and 2 compile and 3, 4 and 5 throw a compile error.

Comment: Hmm. That's strange. I thought I tried all of simple generics like that. Thanks!